# make webpage recognize my own device for debug purpose through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, local-storage, responsive

I build my site with Joomla, by default the page is responsive. I want to turn off responsive design, but there is no turning off option on back-end, so I had to use:

```
  $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=1200px');
```

to turn off responsive so that I didn't have to bother with mobile layout .... for a while. Now the site is live, and I am about to start to make the page responsive. I want to debug this on the live page but don't want other users to see some messed up page when I am still tweaking it. So I am thinking whether there is a way to make the page recognize my own devices only.

I understand that I can use login system, but that would be too complicated. The simplest way I can think of is to do this

```
  if (location.search.indexOf('nores') < 0) {
    j('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=1200px');
  }
```

and then open each page like this `mystie.com?nores`. But this is still a little troublesome, besides I can't freely navigate pages.

The other way I was able to find out is to add some custom string to `userAgent`, I think this can be done through chrome's developer tools, but what about mobile browser? Similar is using `localStorage`, on PC, I can just open the page, go to console and do `localStorage.setItem('nores',true)`, but how can I do this for my phone?

Comment: Why do you want to develop on your production server? That is a recipe for disaster. Replicate your website and database into a local sandbox environment and do things there.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter much. Besides something depends on the server environment to run. Another reason is that someone else is adding content to the website, if I download a backup and develop in my local machine, it will be hard to sync later.

Comment: You can debug mobile chrome from a desktop browser. Google it

Comment: Proper source control is the way you would handle multiple people working on the environment. While it may be fine in this specific case (and therefore let's figure out a way to get you up and running), it might be worth investing the time down the road to properly managing your development pipeline. It can streamline the process immensely and get rid of otherwise-terrible situations.

Comment: Thanks @Thebluefish. I actually have two questions for this: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-use-git-to-version-control-joomla-websites-debugging-and-development, http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/joomla-site-working-with-githubor-any-other-version-control-system but I haven't been able to find out a way yet.